# Paging in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The documentation in Microsoft Graph's ListMessages (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) talks about paging size default being 10 messages. However, when trying to sync huge number of messages this will result in undesirable number of GET requests to Exchange, causing a very bad experience for the user.

Is there any way for the client to specify minimum Paging size for Graph responses? What other workarounds are available for tackling this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSGraph set query page size (instead of using skip token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892790/msgraph-set-query-page-size-instead-of-using-skip-token)

Comment: If you are trying to "sync huge amount of messages", then delta is the way to go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages

Comment: @PaulSchaeflein Thanks for the response. But not sure how delta will help in reducing number of requests when number of messages is huge. As far as I know it is only used to track changes for subsequent syncs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that page you have a title that says **Optional query parameters**:

[OData Query Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/graph/query-parameters)

There you can see the list of parameters you can send.

You should use `$top` parameter to get the number of results you want to receive in each query. You can then create pagination manually with `$skip` parameter, or use the [automatic skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/graph/query-parameters#skiptoken-parameter).

Copied from the first link:

> Use the **$top** query parameter to specify the page size of the result set.
>
> The **$skiptoken** parameter contains an opaque token that references the next page of results and is returned in the URL provided in the @odata.nextLink property in the response.
>
> Use the **$skip** query parameter to set the number of items to skip at the start of a collection

Regards

PD: an example to get the first 20 mails of the logged user  `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$top=20`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did have a look into $top but looks like things like delta queries donot honor $top parameter and page the results anyway.

Comment: note that the Graph API has a rate limit - which is briefly mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65317711/6908282)