# How to get full response or set pagination using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am not sure if my API has the limit for the response.

My Graph API is the following.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children`

Actually, the `children` has more than 1,500 results(folders and files), but it responses only 1206 results.

Does the API provide limited response?

I tried to add some filters including `$top`, `$skip`, etc, but they were not working.

And when I tried to add `?$skip=1000` to get skip 1,000 results, but it was saying the error.

[image]

Please let me know what I should do to get full results or add some filters to paginate using the API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I should use `"@odata.nextLink"` property while it does exist.
You could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

Answer (score 1):

Drive apis have service limitations as mentioned here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#files-and-lists-service-limits and here is the guidance on how to handle throttling issues - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#files-and-lists-service-limits

This method supports the **$expand** and **$select** OData query parameters to customize the response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am not sure how to get the rest of the results using `$expand` or`$select`.