# How to use the Pagination in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to be able to retrieve all users in my Azure Active Directory and cache it so I could filter my users on demande. I know about the nextLink used for Pagination. I'm fairly new in the React world and Javascript so I need some help understanding how to cycle through all pages to get all my users. Here's the code I have right now :

```
    export async function searchADUser(searchQuery?: string, filter: string, orderBy: string = 'displayName') 
{
  const searchedUser = await graphClient!
    .api('/users')
    .header('ConsistencyLevel', 'eventual')
    .filter(`${filter}`)
    .search(`"${searchQuery}"`)
    .orderby(`${orderBy}`)
    .get();

  const nextLink = searchedUser["@odata.nextLink"]

  return searchedUser;
```

I was able to access the nextLink url using the ["@odata.nextLink"]. So my question is how to get all users ? Do I just loop until nextLink is null or there is a better way.

Thank you

Comment: According to Microsoft you are doing it the correct way : 
"Microsoft Graph will continue to return a reference to the next page of results in the odata.nextLink property with each response until all pages of the results have been read. To read all results, you must continue to all Microsoft Graph with the @odata.nextLink property returned in each response until the odata.nextLink property is no longer returned."

The complete doc is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691200/6908282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code to be able to get all pages of data from a Microsoft Graph :

```
export async function getAllAADUsers(
  authProvider: AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider
) {
  ensureClient(authProvider);

  try {
    let response: PageCollection = await graphClient!.api('/users').get();

    // let allUsers: User[] = [];
    let callback: PageIteratorCallback = (data) => {
      console.log('file: GraphService.tsx ~ line 129 ~ data', data);
      return true;
    };

    let pageIterator = new PageIterator(graphClient!, response, callback);

    await pageIterator.iterate();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
```

That works wonders!

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

> The default and maximum page sizes are 100 and 999 user objects
> respectively

Here's the [api description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) for page size. If user account in your tenant is more than 999, then you have no other choice but to loop the query until there's no nextLink.

If user account is less than 1000, then you may try `.orderby().top(999).get();`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I posted the answer I found to iterate through Microsoft Graph Pagination. I tried the .top(999) but like you said I had more the 1500 users to go through.